# Definition of a principal ultrafilter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, filters

I just started trying to read through Lectures on the Hyperreals: An Introduction to Nonstandard Analysis, by Robert Goldblatt. I'm near the beginning in the section on filters.  He's defined an ultrafilter as follows: Consider a non-empty set $I$ and it's Power Set $\mathcal P(I)$.  An ultrafilter $\mathcal F$ on $I$. contains all supersets of its elements as well as all finite intersections.  Also $A\in$ $\mathcal F$ iff $A^c\notin\mathcal F$.  Where $A^c = I-A$ and $A\in \mathcal P(I)$.

He then goes on to give some examples of filters, including 2 that are examples of "principal ultrafilters", however he doesn't actually define principal ultrafilters.

The first example would be $\mathcal F^i=\{A\subseteq I:i \in A \}$.

The second example is similar, but for a set, rather than a single element.  $\mathcal F^\mathcal H=\{A\subseteq I:A \supseteq B \}$ and $B\ \in \mathcal P(I)$.

I'm unsure of the actual definition of a principal ultrafilter.  It appears that it's a filter generated by an object (via supersets), where that object is either an element of the universe or an element of the power set of the universe.  Along with satisfying the requirements of being an ultrafilter.  Is that correct?

Comment: Are you sure that Goldblatt doesn't *define* principal ultrafilters as the filters $\mathcal{F}^i$?

Comment: For fixed $a$ in $I$, it is the collection of subsets of $I$ that contain $a$. I think of an ultrafilter as a (finitely additive) "measure" on the power set, with values $0$ or $1$, that gives mass $1$ to $I$. A principal ultrafilter assigns mass $1$ to a certain point $a$. Non-principal ultrafilters assign mass $0$ to all points.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese - he does say that it's called the principal ultrafilter generated by i.  But then he goes on to do the same thing with a element of the power set B. Calling this a special case of the situation when B={i}.

Comment: But does he call such things principal ultrafilters?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese - yikes - you're right, he did not.  He called them Principal Filters.  Maybe I need to enroll in a reading class!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Principal filters are filters which has a $\subseteq$ minimum, or in other words $\cal F$ is a principal **filter** if $\bigcap\cal F\in\cal F$. So if $\cal F$ is a principal filter and $A=\bigcap\cal F$ then $\mathcal F=\{B\subseteq X\mid A\subseteq B\}$.

If $\cal F$ is a principal ultrafilter then we can prove that there is a singleton in $\cal F$, which has to be unique. If this singleton is $\{i\}$ then $\mathcal F=\{A\subseteq X\mid\{i\}\subseteq A\}=\{A\subseteq X\mid i\in A\}$.

The proof is not difficult, if $A=\bigcap\cal F$ and $A$ is not a singleton, then $A$ is the disjoint union of $B\cup C$ where neither is empty. Since $A$ is the minimum of $\cal F$ neither $B$ nor $C$ are in $\cal F$; and since it's an ultrafilter $X\setminus B\in\cal F$, and therefore $A\cap(X\setminus B)=C\in\cal F$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Just a note on something that confused me at first because I thought, "filters are only closed under FINITE intersections, not arbitrary ones". A filter $\mathcal{F}$ is of the form $\{ B \subseteq X \mid A \subseteq B \}$ for some $A \subseteq X$ iff $\bigcap \mathcal{F} \in \mathcal{F}$. Left to right: $\bigcap \mathcal{F} = A$. Right to left: $\bigcap \mathcal{F} \subseteq B$ for all $B \in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila♦ I am sorry but I am having a lot of trouble understanding why $F$ is a principal filter if $\bigcap F\in F$...is the definition $F=\{B\subseteq X|A\subseteq B\}$ for $\exists A\subseteq X$ equivalent to $\forall Y\subset I$, $D=\{X\subset I: Y\subset X\}$? I've looked at Marker, Hodges and CC Chang, but none of them seem to define $F$ like the former, and Marker/CC Chang define $F$ as the latter instead

Comment: And what is the $X$ in $F=\{B\subseteq X|A\subseteq B\}$ for $\exists A\subseteq X$ supposed to be? (Please excuse me for these stupid questions as I have literally no background in maths and is trying to pass Model theory...)

Comment: @Daniel: $X$ is just the set on which the filter is defined. Your comments are a bit hard to understand since you're putting unnecessary quantifiers in some places. But if I understand correctly, then yes, $D$ and $F$ are **exactly** the same filter, with just different letters. This is like saying that $|x|<1\to x^2<1$ is hard to understand, because the book you're looking it up in says $0<r<1\to r\cdot r<1$.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila♦ Thank you so much; sorry for the confusion as I was supposed to write $F$ instead of $D$.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila♦ I am sorry I have one more question: how would one prove that $F$ is principal if $\bigcap F\in F$? Since a filter $F\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$, $\bigcap F\in \mathcal{P}(X)$, meaning that $\bigcap F\subseteq X$. But this is as far as I can get.

Comment: @DanielMak: Prove that if $A\in F$, then $\bigcap F\subseteq A$. Which is fairly straightforward.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila♦ So we are trying to prove that $\bigcap F\subseteq A$, and $A$ is just some non-specific set. But if we again let $\bigcap F=A$, then obviously$\bigcap F\subseteq \bigcap F$, which also satisfies our assumption that $\bigcap F\in F$. Is this right?

Comment: @Daniel: No. You assume that $\bigcap F\in F$, and you want to show that there is some set in $F$ which is a subset of every other element of $F$, in other words, that $F$ has a minimum with respect to inclusion. You're making too quick jumps, and you fall. I've been there, and I know it's hard, but work slowly with the definitions. Read this: http://karagila.org/2015/how-to-solve-your-problems/

Comment: @Asaf Karagila♦ Thank you for that; I understand what you said (assume $\bigcap F \in F$, prove that there exists a set $A$ st $A$ is a subset of every element of $F$ other than itself<-which is just what the def. of a principal filter is), but I am confused about proving if $A\in F$ then $\bigcap F\subseteq A$ - is that just math speaks for what I said in the bracket, or is that something different? The $A$ has no quantifier over it so I am also a little confused

Comment: @Asaf Karagila♦ I know this is against the norm of the board but could you give me more direct hints please? I find this so challenging to the point that I have an actual headache thinking about it, and the fact that I know this is supposed to be easy make me feel worse...I have listed everything I know out, but nothing connects at all.

Comment: For what it's worth, I know the following: 1) $\bigcap F\in F$, 2) from the def. of a filter, $X\in F$ and $\bigcap F, X\in F\to \bigcap F\bigcap X\in F$ therefore $\bigcap F\bigcap X\in F$, 3) $\bigcap F=\{y\in B|B\in F\}$. I have a feeling that the crucial point lies in 3), but I don't know what I can do with it.

Comment: @Daniel: The quantifier on $A$ here is universal. That means, take an arbitrary $A\in F$, then $\bigcap F\subseteq A$. For that, prove that if $X$ is any collection of sets, then for all $A\in X$, $\bigcap X\subseteq A$. Try this with $X$ having two sets or three sets, and then see how it generalises to arbitrary $X$ (no, induction is not the right way to do it, before you're going to attempt that).

Comment: @Asaf Karagila♦ We assume $\bigcap F\in F$, and try to prove $\exists A\subseteq X$ st $F=\{B\subseteq X|A\subseteq B\}$. Suppose we have an arbitrary $A\in F$. We have $\bigcap F=\{y\in B|B\in F\}$, meaning that everything in $\bigcap F$ is a member of an arbitrary $B\in F$, therefore for every $y\in\bigcap F$, $y\in A$. Since this $A$ is arbitrary, this applies to every $A\in F$. i.e. $\bigcap F\subseteq A$.

Comment: If we take $\bigcap F$ to be that set, i.e. $F=\{B\subseteq X|\bigcap F\subseteq B\}$, this proves that $\exists A\subseteq X$ st $F=\{B\subseteq X|A\subseteq B\}$. Is this right?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes. This can be written better and more clearly (the use of letters is a bit confusing), but the argument is fine.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila♦ Thank you so much, once I understood that it is $\forall$ that ranges over $A$ it all makes sense. I really appreciate your patience with me!

Answer (score 2):

Goldblatt writes on [page 18](http://books.google.sk/books?id=TII-PX_OdloC&pg=PA18):

> $\mathcal F^i=\{A\subseteq I; i\in A\}$ is an ultrafilter, called the *principal ultrafilter generated by $i$.* If $I$ is finite, then every ultrafilter on $I$ is of the form $\mathcal F^i$.

I think this passage can be considered the definition of *principal ultrafilters*.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be any set and $x \in X$ then a principal ultrafilter is of the form

$$\mathcal{U}=\{ A \subseteq X | x\in A\}.$$

Comment: why the downvote ?